# Set a Default Value For Drupal Profile Multiselect Field

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, user-profile

I'm using Drupal core profile module, with [Profile checkboxes](http://drupal.org/project/profile_checkboxes) to add two custom fields to the user profile.

I need to set a default value for those two fields, for instance, make the first option checked by default. How can this be done? I'm quite newbie at Drupal development, but any guidance will be appreciated.

I'm using Druapl 6.22, Profile 6.22, & Profile Checkboxes 6.x-1.2

I searched, & get this:

```
<?php
function my_module_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
    if($form_id == 'user_profile_form') {
        if(arg(0) == 'user' && arg(1)) {
            $user = user_load(arg(1));
                    //Something wrong is here!!!
            $form['test']['profile_test'][1]['#default_value'] = TRUE; 
        }
    }
}
```

This is not working. I don't know how to get the correct field. All I need is to set a default value for the first option in this multiple choice check-box. How??

Answer (score 0):

You can alter that form (for check boxes) in a custom module using form api. Try to alter form using `your_module_form_alter()` in your custom module and set `'#default_value' = true` for any of your check boxes. Assuming you know how to create custom modules.